# how to stop .jsp and html file to download from internet explorer & jquery and javascript not working on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, internet-explorer

I have two problem while using internet explorer... My application is working fine in google chrome.

1) But the same application when it try to run on internet explorer its showing this popup menu with open or save option for the .jsp and html files.

2) I'm adding 4 time text fields in the jsp page which will add all the times and show in another text box. and finally by pressing submit button we'll save data into database. but it is not showing any thing in the internet explorer.. no time field its just a black field. please check the code which is working in google chrome but not in internet explorer.

jsfiddle.net/hes6pkbj/7

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `<input type="date"` &  `<input type="time"` is not suported in ie/mozilla/safari see :http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime